# Python Dictionary, csv, grabbing the value of a key in a dictionary based on another key value

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a sample input csv file (made into a list) that looks like this:

```
Alfa,Beta,Charlie,Delta,Echo,Price1,Price2,Price3
A1,B1,C1,D1,AX1,1000,2000,3000
A2,B2,C2,D2,BX1,1500,2500,3500
A3,B3,C3,D3,CX1,25,50,60
A4,B4,C4,D4,BX1/CX1,10,20,30
A5,B5,C5,D5,CX1/AX1,500,1000,1500
A6,B6,C6,D6,AX1/BX1,25,50,75
```

Then my sample code looks like this:

```
import csv

with open('sample.csv') as csv_file:
    column_numbers = 'Echo'
    ID_dict = {"AX1" : "AA1,AA2",
           "BX1" : "BB1,BB2",
           "CX1" : "CC1,CC2"
           }
    price_dict = {"AX1": Price1, "BX1": Price2, "CX1": Price3}

    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        if row[column_numbers]:
            for ky in row[column_numbers].split('/'): #This will split up 'Echo' into AX1,BX1,CX1, BX1, CX1, CX1, AX1, AX1, BX1
                
                #for item in ID_dict[ky].split(','): 
                    #print(item)
```

This line will split up 'Echo', so when I print it will give me : AX1,BX1,CX1, BX1, CX1, CX1, AX1, AX1, BX1

```
for ky in row[column_numbers].split('/'):
```

Now I need a new column called 'FinalPrice' that will correlate to the Column of 'Echo'

So that the value of AX1 in 'Echo' is = value of 'Price1', BX1 = Price2, CX1 = Price3

I will prob have to add another dictionary:

```
price_dict = {"AX1": Price1, "BX1": Price2, "CX1": Price3}
```

For example for the 1st of the csv, 'Echo' = AX1 then 'FinalPrice' should = 1000, and if the second line of 'Echo' = BX1 then the second line of 'FinalPrice' should = 2500 etc etc

So when I print out 'Echo' and 'FinalPrice', it should look like this:

```
Echo,FinalPrice
    AX1,1000
    BX1,2500
    CX1,60
    BX1,20
    CX1,30
    CX1,1500
    AX1,500
    AX1,25
    BX1,50


This is How the output should look like:

Alfa,Echo,FinalPrice
A1,AX1,1000
A2,BX1,2500
A3,CX1,60
A4,BX1,20
A4,CX1,30
A5,CX1,1500
A5,AX1,500
A6,AX1,25
A6,BX1,50
```

Thank you for all your help <3

Comment: I don't see a point in the convoluted logic using `ID_dict ` and iterating on its keys. From your output, it seems that you simply want to split the column `Echo` on `/` and flatten, then get the value on one of the columns `Price1,Price2,Price3`, according to the map `AX1: Price1, BX1: Price2, CX1: Price3`

Comment: This `for item in ID_dict[ky].split(','): print(item)` does not produce `AX1,BX1,CX1, BX1, CX1, CX1, AX1, AX1, BX1`  as the item values in ` ID_dict` are `"AA1,AA2", "BB1,BB2", "CC1,CC2"`.

Comment: This is correct, if I print(items) it will give me; Echo,FinalPrince 
AA1,1000
AA2,1000
BB1,2500
BB2,2500
CC1,60
CC2,60
BB1,20
BB2,20
CC1,30
CC2,30
CC1,1500
CC2,1500
AA1,500
AA2,500
AA1,25
AA2,25
BB1,50
BB2,50